# Ошибка при реализации работавшего только что кода (JSON.parse: unexpected character)

Tags: javascript, html, json, commonjs

Осваиваю метод, при котором контент (текст) загружается на веб-страницу из json файла. Контент перед помещение на страницу компилируется с handlebars templates. Javascript файлы с логикой для всего этого, написаны как модули commonjs, скопилированные с помощью browserify. Страницу запускаю с локальный http сервером, установленным с помощью NodeJS npm.

Тестовый пример работал, при попытке применить этот метод к готовой веб-странице, что-то идет не так. Так как только осваиваю этот метод, буду благодарен за помощь.

Итак, имеется:

- **webContent.json** - в нем хранится контент (текст), который будет подгружен в **index.html**
- **contentProcess.js** - содержит функцию, которая послает Ajax запрос к **webContent.json**, парсит, компилирует с `Handlebars Template` и
  помещает контент на страницу (с помощью innerHTML)
- **addContent.js** - вызывает функцию из **contentProcess.js**, подставив нужные переменные. **contentProcess.js** и
  **addContent.js** написаны и связаны как `commonjs` модули. Затем они компилируются в **main.js** с помощью `browserify`.
- **index.html** - содержит в себе `Handlebars Template`, `div`, куда будет помещен контент и линк на **main.js**

Тестовая версия работала. Когда попытался реализовать этот подход с уже имеющейся веб-страницей, что-то не работает. Консоль жалуется на часть логики из **main.js**, которая изначально была частью функции в  **contentProcess.js**, которая в тестовом примере работала без проблем (ниже два скриншота):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем здесь проблема (в тестовой версии эта функция работала)?

В снипите разбросал фрагменты кода из всех вышеперечисленных файлов (разделив комментариями):

```js
/* --- webContent.json --- */
{
header: "Powerful business", 
describtion: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis neque, sodales a faucibus at, viverra luctus urna. Suspendisse dignissim neque dui, in tincidunt arcu.'
}


/* --- contentProcess.js --- */

module.exports = function(jsonDir, templId, finId){
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    /*reference json url taken from: http://www.jsontest.com/*/

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "http://date.jsontest.com/" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', jsonDir);

    /*Using onload event handler you can check status of your request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler you can check error state, if your request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById(templId).innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById(finId).innerHTML += template(response);
})
}


/* --- addContent.js --- */
var addContent = require('./contentProcess');
addContent("../data/webContent.json", "main-template", 'maintext');
```

```css
/* --- main.js (после компиляции addContent.js с помощью browserify) --- */

(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var addContent = require('./contentProcess');

/*MAINBLOCK*/ 
addContent("../data/webContent.json", "main-template", 'maintext');
},{"./contentProcess":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){

module.exports = function(jsonDir, templId, finId){
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    /*reference json url taken from: http://www.jsontest.com/*/

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "http://date.jsontest.com/" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', jsonDir);

    /*Using onload event handler you can check status of your request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler you can check error state, if your request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById(templId).innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById(finId).innerHTML += template(response);
})
}



},{}]},{},[1]);
```

```html
<!-- фрагмент кода из index.html (на странице используется bootstrap, если это имеет значение) -->

<div id="maintext"> </div>
                     <script id="main-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                    {{{header}}} {{{describtion}}} {{{sentence3}}}
                     </script>
```

Comment: Слишком много подробностей. Попробуйте сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример, тогда понять в чем проблема будет проще, и вам и нам.

Comment: @Утка Да, как раз собирался его сделать.

Comment: @Утка Но боюсь он будет не намного проще - здесь я по-сути убрал все лишнее... но сделаю отдельную версию и добавлю ссылку на скачивание.

Comment: @Утка Создал тему где можно скачать работающий пример и с неработающий (с урезанной версией веб-страницы к которой я пытаюсь применить этот же метод). http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562324/195703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(может не повезёт, но попробую угадать)

```
/* --- webContent.json --- */
{
header: "Powerful business", 
describtion: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis neque, sodales a faucibus at, viverra luctus urna. Suspendisse dignissim neque dui, in tincidunt arcu.'
}
```

Это не JSON, в JSON ключи без кавычек недопустимы и все кавычки должны быть только двойными, должно быть так

```
{
"header": "Powerful business", 
"describtion": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis neque, sodales a faucibus at, viverra luctus urna. Suspendisse dignissim neque dui, in tincidunt arcu."
}
```

`/* Комментарии */` в JSON тоже запрещены, да.

Comment: Да, я уже тоже заметил, все верно, спасибо. Но после исправления все равно не работает. Готовлю упрощенный пример.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Значит после исправления по идее должна возникать другая ошибка, а если так, то это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Ок, тогда ответ принят, спасибо.

Comment: Создал тему где можно скачать работающий пример и с неработающий (с урезанной версией веб-страницы к которой я пытаюсь применить этот же метод). http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562324/195703

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за исправление в синтаксисе JSON, но ошибка, скриншот которой я поместил выше после исправления остается...
Насколько я понял, консоль жалуется на эту строку:  `callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));`

Comment: Значит надо посмотреть, что за фигню вы скармливаете в JSON.parse, поставив перед этой строкой `console.log(xhr.responseText)`

Comment: Большое спасибо еще раз!) Причина оказалась до смешного проста - мешал комментарий в JSON файле, насколько я теперь понимаю, их там вообще не может быть...